# BIRT: Getting started with the Chart API

Tags: eclipse-rcp, birt

So I need a few simple pointers with the BIRT chart API.

I am trying to draw a simple line chart of a numeric value over time. I have a vector of (Date,Double) pairs as input. I have read through the examples in org.eclipse.birt.chart.examples but not yet gained enough traction with the API to start making use of it. Just composing a org.eclipse.birt.chart.model.impl.ChartWithAxesImpl has me stumped.

The eventual destination is an Eclipse editor, and that I can do. Is there a tutorial or book anyone can recommend that might get me going with the BIRT chart side?

I should be very grateful

M.

Answer (score 0):

Well. There is this example: http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-BIRTChartEngine/index.html

But I am having some problems actually getting it to work myself. All I end up with is an exception like this:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.eclipse.birt.chart.device.swt.SwtTextMetrics.getHeight(SwtTextMetrics.java:178)
at org.eclipse.birt.chart.computation.Methods.computeFontHeight(Methods.java:1272)
at org.eclipse.birt.chart.computation.BIRTChartComputation.computeFontHeight(BIRTChartComputation.java:30)
at org.eclipse.birt.chart.computation.EllipsisHelper$SimpleTester.<init>(EllipsisHelper.java:213)
at org.eclipse.birt.chart.computation.EllipsisHelper.createSimpleTester(EllipsisHelper.java:176)
at org.eclipse.birt.chart.computation.EllipsisHelper.simpleInstance(EllipsisHelper.java:183)
at org.eclipse.birt.chart.computation.LabelLimiter.limitLabelSize(LabelLimiter.java:256)
at org.eclipse.birt.chart.computation.LabelLimiter.limitLabelSize(LabelLimiter.java:211)
at org.eclipse.birt.chart.model.layout.impl.TitleBlockImpl.computeBox(TitleBlockImpl.java:288)
at org.eclipse.birt.chart.model.layout.impl.LabelBlockImpl.getPreferredSize(LabelBlockImpl.java:266)
at org.eclipse.birt.chart.internal.layout.LayoutManager$ChartLayout.<init>(LayoutManager.java:111)
at org.eclipse.birt.chart.internal.layout.LayoutManager.doLayout_tmp(LayoutManager.java:1145)
at org.eclipse.birt.chart.internal.layout.LayoutManager.doLayout(LayoutManager.java:1310)
at org.eclipse.birt.chart.factory.Generator.build(Generator.java:1092)
```

Comment: Ah. I finally figured out why the linked example is not working. It does not set GC on render early enough. render.setProperty(IDeviceRenderer.GRAPHICS_CONTEXT, gc) needs to be called before the Generator#build call

Answer (score 0):

I had the same trouble with the examples from `org.eclipse.birt.chart.examples`. There are some good java code snippets, but you do not see to what they correspond. This is why I decided to generate all the examples and put them on a web site: [BIRT Charts Gallery](http://jmini.developpez.com/eclipse_birt/charting_engine/gallery/).