# How to view BIRT reports using Java in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, sqlite, birt

I'm creating an appointment booking and financial application for a start-up business opening soon. Everything is going well and I'm nearing the end of this project, yet I would like to create reports that the user can run, print and export. I have added the BIRT developer into Eclipse and have successfully created several reports which preview well. What I would like to know is how I can get the reports to run from Java code? I have searched the web for ages and have not found a solution. The reports are sitting in the same project folder as all my classes.

Your help is most appreciated..

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the most common way of sharing BIRT reports is to use Apache Tomcat.  This tool allows the report to be run as HTML, PDF, Excel 2003, and a number of other formats. As both BIRT and Apache Tomcat are open source, initiation is not as simple as more costly products but there are a number of solutions on the web for any problem you might encounter.

http://tomcat.apache.org/

Comment: Thanks I did start to use BIRT, yet I found it too over complicated to administer for what I needed it for. I found Jasper Reports much easier to install and use, without the need to install Tomcat.

Answer (score 2):

If your application is a web application you can use BIRT engine inside your WAR and create all your reports and charts, and then share them using the application server. 
Otherwise, if your application is an Eclipse based application, I think you should use the BIRT eclipse plugin, that contains the engine, to build reports and then you can use the default eclipse file association to show them to users (ie using internal browser).

Comment: look at [this for RCP case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7365681/birt-getting-started-with-the-chart-api)